# How to wait for a thunk action creator to dispatch when calling it for validation?

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I have a very simple redux-thunk action creator that posts some values then dispatches a response, either {} if successful, or the database entry that would cause a conflict (the field has be to unique).

```
export const playerSubmit = (values) => async dispatch => {
     const res = await axios.post('/api/player/add', values);

     dispatch({ type: FETCH_PLAYER, payload: res.data });
}
```

I'm trying to do a react/redux-form validation where I wait for the response before checking if the action returned the conflict or not, but I'm having trouble finding something that works. I have every other part of the validation working, how do I get the code to wait for the dispatch to finish before continuing?